# PIVOT issue in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, in-clause

I am not able to troubleshoot an issue with my pivot function in SQL. I want to preserve the uid column, but have only one row per uid in my result + columns for sc_2015, sc_2016, sc_2017, etc. (In the original table, there is one uid row per year per month + the score column.)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.uid,
        t2.score_year AS yr,
        --averaging scores across 12-months per year per uid:
        CAST(AVG(t2.score) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.uid,t2.score_year) AS DECIMAL(4,3)) AS avg_annual_score
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.uid
    =
    t2.uid
WHERE t2.score_year IN (
  '2015',
  '2016',
  '2017',
  '2018',
  '2019')
)
PIVOT (
MAX(avg_annual_score) sc FOR yr IN (
  '2015',
  '2016',
  '2017',
  '2018',
  '2019')
);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The dbms is SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to suggest ditching the `PIVOT` operator and instead just using an old school pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    t1.uid,
    AVG(CASE WHEN t2.score_year = 2015 THEN t2.score END) AS avg_score_2015,
    AVG(CASE WHEN t2.score_year = 2016 THEN t2.score END) AS avg_score_2016
    AVG(CASE WHEN t2.score_year = 2017 THEN t2.score END) AS avg_score_2017,
    AVG(CASE WHEN t2.score_year = 2018 THEN t2.score END) AS avg_score_2018
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.uid = t2.uid
GROUP BY
    t1.uid;
```

The reason I suggest not using `PIVOT` is that in many cases the above version would actually perform better.  And IMHO the code is a bit easier to read and maintain.

**Edit:**

A possibly write `PIVOT` version would look like this:

```
SELECT uid, [2015], [2016], [2017], [2018]
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.uid, t2.score, t2.score_year
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.uid = t2.uid
    WHERE t2.score_year BETWEEN 2015 AND 2018
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    AVG(score)
    FOR score_year IN ([2015], [2016], [2017], [2018])
) AS pivotal;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works fantastic. :) Do you happen to know what the issue was in my PIVOT in my query? (It will bother me until I figure it out lol.)

Comment: @es_analytics Sadly I don't...mainly because I tend to avoid `PIVOT`, and also most folks on SO don't use it so often.